# SELECT specific records when DISTINCT wont make it

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables:

```
tbl_Artist
AristID
Name
Info
```

And

```
tbl_Ad
AdID
ArtistID
Venue
DateFrom
DateTo
```

An artist may have several ads for different shows. I run the following statement to select what artists are in town on a date-range based on the dates in the ads.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_Artist.Name, tbl_Ad.DateFrom, tbl_Ad.DateTo
FROM tbl_Artist INNER JOIN tbl_Ad ON tbl_Ad.AdID = tbl_Ad.ArtistID
WHERE DateFrom BETWEEN #12/1/2014# AND #12/10/2014#
OR DateTo BETWEEN #12/1/2014# AND #12/10/2014#
OR DateFrom < #12/1/2014# AND DatoTo > #12/10/2014#;
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
Artist1   02.12.14 - 10.12.14
Artist2   03.12.13 - 08.12.14
Artist2   03.12.13 - 07.12.14
```

The date on one of the shows ends one day before the other, which makes him come up twice. I want to make a selection that shows 2 artist on 07.12.14 and 08.12.14, but only one on 10.12.14.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You lucked out here because of the conditions chosen, but **always** use parenthesis when you mix `AND` and `OR` conditions, to make it clearer for human readers.  When dealing with date and time types, it's best to use [ISO Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), or values may be ambiguous across different cultures (Are we talking about December, or October and January?).  Please also avoid using `BETWEEN` [with non-integral types like date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), or at all.

Comment: Thanks for the Feedback! I am still a bit new to this, so I am very grateful for every bit of help I receive. Also thanks for including the links so I can read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all something is shocking me : `FROM tbl_Artist INNER JOIN tbl_Ad ON tbl_Ad.AdID = tbl_Ad.ArtistID` the join clause should be `tbl_Ad.ArtistID = tbl_Artist.AristID`

One the second hand, you need to see only 1 row for artist show have 2 different dates : end/start date of shows ends on the same range of dates... I want to say : why in your database your artists have many shows ends that have dates intersecting ? But I think this is because of the error in join clause. Try to re-run your query with the good join.

If that persists, you can use `MIN()` and `MAX()` function to get the max range of dates for retrieved ads by artist :

```
SELECT
    Name
    ,MIN(DateFrom)
    ,MAX(DateTo)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        tbl_Artist.Name
        , tbl_Ad.DateFrom
        , tbl_Ad.DateTo
    FROM 
        tbl_Artist 
        INNER JOIN tbl_Ad 
            ON tbl_Ad.ArtistID = tbl_Artist.AristID
    WHERE 
        DateFrom BETWEEN #12/1/2014# AND #12/10/2014#
        OR DateTo BETWEEN #12/1/2014# AND #12/10/2014#
        OR DateFrom < #12/1/2014# AND DatoTo > #12/10/2014#)
GROUP BY
    Name;
```